# How to give Line chart option in d3 chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts

I am having a d3 chart in which bar chart is the type but i want to include the line chart type as well.I want to give both options at the web page so user can switch between any either bar chart or line chart.please suggest how can I do that
below is my html

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <title>D3</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css" /> -->

        <style>
            body {
                color: #000;
            }

            .axis {
                font: 10px sans-serif;
            }

            .axis path,
            .axis line {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #000;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

            .bar {
                fill: steelblue;
            }

            .bar:hover {
                fill: brown;
            }


            #upleft { width:320px; height: 600px; background:red; float:left; }
            #upright { width:800px; height:50px; background:green; float:left }
            #below { height:600px; width:1120px; background:blue }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="123.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <body>
      <div id="upleft">
    <label> List of Tables : </label><br>
    <div>
            <select id="dropdown1"></select>
       </div>
        <style>
            #listbox {
                display: none;
            }
            #listbox {
                position: relative;
            }
        </style>
        <div style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: -30px; height: auto;">

            <select id="listbox", multiple></select>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="upright">
        <div align="left">
        From : <input type="date" name="field1" id="field1" /> To : <input type="date" name="field2" id="field2" />
        <input type="button" onclick="render(true)" value="Submit"/>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="below">

    <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var jsonURL = 'avb.json';
        var myData = [];
        var fliterdata=[];
        var tempdata=[];
        var selectop="";
         var selectDate = false;
    function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
       var result = [];
      for (var foo in json) {

        if (json[foo][key] == value) {
          result.push(json[foo]);


        }
      }
      return result;
    }

    function selectValue(d){
       // console.log("before op",selectop );
      switch(selectop){   //d object select particular value for Y axis 
                case "01":
                    return d.val001;
                    break;
                case "02":
                    return d.val002;
                    break;
                case "03":
                    return d.val003;
                    break;
                case "04":
                    return d.val004;
                    break;
                case "05":
                    return d.val005;
                    break;
                default:
                    //console.log("default");
                    return d.val001;
            }  
     }
            var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 80,
            left: 40
        };
        var width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right;
        var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
        var hAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom').tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
        var vAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
        var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
                .style('position', 'absolute')
                .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
                .style('padding', '5 15px')
                .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
                .style('border-radius', '5px')
                .style('opacity', 'o');

   function render(filterByDates) {
            d3.select('svg').remove();

            if (filterByDates) {
                    selectDate=true;
                    tempData=fliterdata;
                    console.log("before date fliter data", tempData);
                var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('field1').value);
                var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('field2').value);

                 tempData = tempData.filter(function(d) {
                    console.log(date1,date2);
                  //  alert(date1);
                    return d.date >= date1 && d.date <= date2;


                });
                    console.log("After date fliter data", tempData);
            }


            xScale.domain(tempData.map(function(d) {
                        return d.date;
                    })  .sort(function(a,b) {
                      return a > b;
                    })
            );

            yScale.domain([0, d3.max(tempData, function(d) {
                return +selectValue(d);
            })]);

            var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
                   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")
                   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            svg

                    .append('g')
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(hAxis)
                    .selectAll("text")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

            svg
                    .append('g')
                    .attr("class", "yaxis")
                    .call(vAxis)

            svg
                    .selectAll(".bar") //makes bar
                    .data(tempData)
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .style("fill", "red")
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                        return xScale(d.date);
                    })



                    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                    .attr("y", function(d) {


                        return yScale(selectValue(d));
                    })
                    .attr("height", function(d) {

                        console.log("as", d.value);
                        return height - yScale(selectValue(d));
                    })

        }
        d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {

            myData = data; //data from json in mydata
            myData.forEach(function(d) {

                d.date = new Date(d.date);
                //d.value="";

                //d.name = +d.name;
                console.log(d.date,"Gt date");
                d.date = new Date(d.date + " UTC");
                console.log(d.date,"localtimezone date");
            });

             $("#listbox").on("click", function() {

                var key = $(this).val();
                console.log("key:", key);
                var value=$('#listbox option:selected').text();
                console.log("vaue:", value);

                selectop=String(key);

                selectop=selectop.slice(-2);
                 console.log("mydata: ", myData);
                 console.log("selectops:",selectop );

                fliterdata=filterJSON(myData, key, value); 
                tempData=fliterdata;  //graph made by temp data
                if (selectDate)
                        render(true);
              });   
        });
    </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please try to clean up your code a little before asking someone to review it for you.  All the whitespace (7 blank lines between function calls is excessive) makes it harder to read.

Comment: Have cleaned the code now!!!

Comment: If you know how to make a bar chart in d3 you can make a line chart. Create a control element - 2 radio buttons, or a 2 option select element, etc. When the user selects the line chart, call the code that will create the line chart on another svg element.

Comment: i dont know where can i implement line chart